# Is it better to repeat "rows" or "columns" when designing for app-engine datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm fairly new to the app-engine datastore but get that it is designed more like a Hashtable than a database table. This leads me to think it's better to have fewer rows (entities) and more columns (object properties) "in general".

That is, you can create a `Car` object with properties `color` and `count` or you can create it with properties `redCount`, `blueCount`, `greenCount`, assuming you know all the colors (dimensions). If you are storing instances of those objects you would have either three or one:

For each color and count, save new entity:
`"red", 3` 
`"blue", 8` 
`"green", 4`

Or save one entity with properties for each possible color: `3, 8, 4`

Obviously there are some design challenges with the latter approach but wondering what the advice is for getting out of relational thinking? Seems datastore is quite happy with hundreds of "columns" / properties.

Comment: Continuing with your example, do you know what all the colours will ever be for cars added to this system in the future? If not, then you can't use the later approach.

Comment: There are no columns in the data store.  You need to stop thinking in those terms.  There is entity identified by a key and a set of indexes based on the key and one or more properties values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good job trying to get out of relational thinking.  It's good to move away from the row/table thinking.

A closer approximation, at least on the programming side, would be to think of entities as data structure or class instances stored remotely.  These entities have properties.  Separate from the entities are indexes, which essentially store lists of entities that match certain criteria for properties.

When you write an entity, the datastore updates that instance in memory/storage, and then updates all the indexes.

When you do a query, you essentially walk through  one of the index lists.

That should give you a basic framework to think about the datastore.

When you design for the datastore, you generally have to design for cost, and to a lesser degree, performance.  On the write side, you want to minimize the number of indexes.  On the read side, you want to minimize the number of entities you're reading, so the idea of having separate entities for red, blue, green could be a bad idea, tripling your read costs if you constantly need to read back the number of red/blue/green cars.  There could be some really obscure corner case where this makes sense.

Your design considerations generally should go along the lines of:

1. What types of queries do I need to do?
2. How do I structure my data to make these queries easy to do (since the GAE query capabilities are limited)?  Would a query be easier if I duplicate data somehow, and would I be able to maintain this duplicated data on my own?
3. How can I minimize the number of indexes that need to be updated when I update an entity?
4. Are there any special cases where I must have full consistency and therefore need to adjust the structure so that consistent queries can be made?
5. Are there any write performance cases I need to be careful about.

Without knowing exactly what kind of query you're going to make, this answer will likely not be right, but it should illustrate how you might want to think of this.

I'll assume you have an application where people register their cars, and you have some dashboard that polls the datastore and displays the number of cars of each color, the traditional mechanism of having a Car class with color, count attributes still makes sense because it minimizes the number of indexed properties, thus reducing your write costs.

It's a bit of an odd example, because I can't tell if you want to just have a single entity that keeps track of your counts (in which case you don't even need to do a query, you can just fetch that count), or if you have a number of entities of counts that you may fetch and sum up.

If user updates modify the same entity though, you might run into performance problems, you should read through this: https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not storing things in your own standard in the one cell. Unless it is encoded in JSON or something similar.

`{'red':3, 'blue':4}`

JSON is ok because it can be easily decoded into a data structure within java like a list or something.

There is nothing wrong with lots of columns in an app.  You will get more gains by having a column for red, blue and green. There would have to be a very large number of columns to see a big slow down.

Answer (score 0):

I think it safe to say that there is no significant performance penalty for having a lot of properties (columns) for each entity (row) in a database model. Nor is there a penalty for lots of rows (entities), or even lots of tables (db classes). If I were doing your example, I would definitely set up separate properties for color and count. We always explicitly call out indexed=False/True to ensure we avoid the dread problem of wondering why your indexes are so large when you only have a few properties indexed (forgetting that the default is True). Although GAE gives you nice properties such as lists that can be indexed, these specialized properties are not without their overhead costs. Understand these well whenever you use them.

One thing that I think is important to remember with GAE when plotting your design is that standard queries are slow, and slow equates to increased latency, and increased latency results in more instances, and more expense (and other frustrations). Before defaulting to a standard query, always ask (if this is a mission-critical part of your code) if you can accomplish the same by setting up a more denormalized datastructure. For example, linking a set of entities together using a common key then doing a series of get_by_id() calls can often be advantageous (be sure to manage ndb's auto memcache when doing this - not everything needs to be cached). Ancestor queries are also much faster than standard queries (but impose a 1 update per second limit on the family group.)

Concluding: within reason the number properties (columns) in an entity (rows) and also the total number of classea (tables) will not impose any real issues. However, if you are coming from a standard relational DB background, your inclination will be to use SQL-like queries to move your logic along. Remember in GAE that standard GQL queries are slow and costly, and always think about things links using denormalization to avoid them. GAE is a big, flat, highly performant noSQL-like resource. Use it as such. Take the extra time to avoid reliance on GQL queries, it will be worth it.